# How to fix 'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:element not interactable' error for a button component?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a travel website using Selenium Webdriver with 
Java wherein I have to add number of Adults and Children from a dropdown 
panel by clicking on a plus icon (button).How do I write the xpath for 
the plus icon which is a button element. HTML code is given below:

I have tried using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='uitk-col all-col-shrink']")).click();
```

But this does not work.It throws an error as 'element not interactable

HTML code of plus icon:

```
<div class="uitk-col all-col-shrink">
  <button type="button" class="uitk-step-input-button uitk-step-input-plus">
    <span class="uitk-icon" data-control="uitk-icon">
      <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="uitk-icon-svg uitk-step-input-icon">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="visuallyhidden traveler-increment">Add Adult to Room 1</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the button, you have to use the correct web element. You are choosing the `div`element encasing the `button` element. There is no native feature to interact with this and there is no event handler registered.

In your case this should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='uitk-step-input-button']")).click();
```

Maybe you will have to adjust the XPath to

```
"//button[contains(@class, 'uitk-step-input-button') and contains(@class, 'uitk-step-input-plus')]"
```